# Will kotlin knowledge of android 12 be useless when android 13 arrives?

Tags: android, kotlin

I think I am not understanding how the programming knowledge of Android Studio works. I mean, I have seen many courses on the internet that are focused in a certain version of Android Studio. So if I learn Kotlin of android 10 will be useless beause now only Kotilin of android 12 is usefull? Will i have to learn a new kotlin lenguage everytime a new version of android is comming? I am studying the programming language of "c" and it doesn´t matter what version you are using that everything you learned of "c" will be useful for any period of time. But I have seen that in kotlin is different,so, does the programming language of Kotlin change depending on the version of android that you are working on? What is the difference between working on Kotlin android version 11 that Kotlin android version 12 on Android Studio? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old, abandoned Android apps generally work perfectly fine without modifications on newer devices - I still use plenty of such apps to this day.

However, if you were the developer of such an app, and you wanted to, say, push a small update to fix one minor thing, you would be forced to update your app to meet the standards of current Android versions first, or otherwise your update wouldn't be accepted on Google Play.

Example: in the past apps used to ask for all the permissions at once before installing, and while you probably can still find such apps in the Play Store, you wouldn't be able to publish such an app nowadays.

Instead, you would need to adapt your hypothetical old app to use this new pattern of asking for permissions right before they are needed first.

---

The Kotlin programming language is the same Kotlin programming language, there are no differences here between Android versions. New Kotlin releases generally only add new language features, they don't delete anything that matters, there is no need for you to worry about this.

---

For each Android app you make you choose a ***target Android version*** and ***minimum Android version*** (you can change them later).

#### Target version

The *target version* should generally be the current most up-to-date Android version. That is the version of Android that you designed your app in mind with. You should only later increase this number after you learn what the new guidelines, standards, features, etc. are in the new Android version - you will often need to change something in your app when you decide to "upgrade".

#### Minimum version

The *minimum version* is the oldest version that you want to have to keep in mind.

I don't really have good examples at hand here, but imagine support for flashlights was added in Android 5. So if set your minimum version to, say, Android 3, you would need to add a condition if your code to define what happens when the user is on Android 3 or 4 that doesn't have the support for flashlights. You would need to display a message to them for example, or make the your flashlight button grayed out and unclickable.

On the other hand, you could just set the minimum version to Android 5, and then you wouldn't have to write this code, because you could just assume that all devices that will be able to run your app know what a flashlight is. So that's less hassle for you, but it also means that less devices will be able to use your app.

Answer (score 5):

No it won't be useless. You need to distinguish between the programming language Kotlin and the Android Framework and its APIs.

If a new Android version comes out, it doesn't mean we start writing apps from tabula rasa.

Every year, with a new Android version, Google introduces a few changes to how things work or extend the capabilities. For us as Android developers that means that we might need to consider new restrictions to permission management or things like that.

To summarize: The Android OS version has nothing to do with the programming language Kotlin itself. You are programming against the Android API version using Kotlin. You don't need to learn everything from the beginning when the next Android version comes out.

Comment: So why some people in these courses that are of Kotlin of Android 10 say it is outdated? I mean, if I learn from a course with Android 10, if Kotlin has nothing to do with the android version, why will I have to change code of Kotlin for android 12?  , will I need to change some functions ?. Another question, what does it mean to be programming in Android 12? Does it mean that the app will be compatible with android versions from 1 to 12? For example if I am programming in Android 10, will the app be only compatible with android versions from 1 to 10 only?

Comment: as this answer has already stated - `You need to distinguish between the programming language Kotlin and the Android Framework and its APIs.` "I mean, if I learn from a course with Android 10, if Kotlin has nothing to do with the android version, why will I have to change code of Kotlin for android 12?" kotlin is what you use to make android apps. think of a phone from ten years ago, do you think it has the same functionality as a modern phone today ? obviously not. as android changes, so will your code, but whether you use java or kotlin or something else is quite irrelevant here.

Comment: So the only thing that it changes is that newer android versions have more functionalities? So an app that is orientated to android 10 won´t be compatible with android 11 or 12, will it?

Comment: that's impossible for us to answer, it depends on the features and what you're doing. i can't predict what will change with android version 15 or 20. will 90% of the functionality stay the same between one version and the next, most likely. will an app targeted for 10 still work for 11 and 12, most likely. can i say that as a fact for every single possible feature - no

Comment: think about what you're asking like this - do you imagine that we have to rewrite all of ours apps for every single version of android, from 1 - X where X keeps increasing constantly ? that sounds a bit extreme

Comment: So imagine this case, I make an app that is compatible with android 12. Imagine that now we are in 2027  and android 17 is the newest. If the apk was produced and published on the google play store in 2022, will the app that was made for android 12 now be working for android 17?, I mean all the developers that are making now apps and publishing them on the google play store sooner or later,will they have to remake and republish the app on the google play store changing that 10% of code per newer android version that you were talking  about?

Comment: Well, there’s a new Google Play store requirement that you must recompile your app to target newer versions of Android within a year of their release. Before they added this rule, your app that you released targeting Android 2.1 ten years ago would still be on the store and working fine on modern phones. When you make an app, you specify a `minSdkVersion` and a `targetSdkVersion` which represents the range of versions your app is compatible with. Later versions of Android usually will not prevent apps with lower targets from working.

Comment: @Tenfour04, lets see if I have understood it. When the apk is released to the play store, it will be compatible with all the future android devices , but the problem is when updating the app for an update because a new target version will be required and the code should be working on that target version, am I right?. But I don´t understand why apps that were uploaded many years ago will work on newer android versions if their target version is much lower? Imagine that one app had a target version of android 9, why will it work on 12 without updating the target version to 12 instead of 9?

Comment: Do all of your apps on your PC or Mac stop working every time they release a new OS version? Most will continue working fine. Occasionally some apps will stop working because of security requirement change. Newer versions of Android often *take away* features for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Changing Android versions means improving Android phones operation system with new features. It does not have any kind of impact on Kotlin or Java language. You will use same Kotlin for all Android versions.

Comment: So if I learn of a course of android 10 I will be able to make apps compatible from versions of Android equal or lower to 10 only?